# What information to provide for an overseas bank transfer?

Tags: authentication

Is it safe to provide someone with your bank account number, swift code and branch code for an overseas transaction who is not known to you personally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe, although this information qualify as personal identifiable information (PII), yet they are needed for transaction, as long as the person doesn't ask for information that are needed for authorization such as PIN, Credit CARD CVV/CVC etc. you are fine.

As usual ensure due diligence when sharing your information